# In WPF textBox, enter does not add a new line

Tags: wpf, textbox, word-wrap

Text box is defined in following code:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsDescriptionReadOnly}" AcceptsReturn="True"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>e
```

When enter is pressed, a new line is not inserted. How to fix this problem?

Comment: +1 for `AcceptsReturn` that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I had similar problem, 
I solved it with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865375/start-a-new-line-in-wpf-textbox) using  `AcceptsReturn="True"`. So I think, this should work.

Answer (score 6):

What you have should work fine, assuming

1. IsReadOnly is false. If you set this to true, then obviously the Enter key won't work.
2. The control containing the TextBox is not clipping the TextBox, so it appears that the Enter key did not work.

I'd suggest you try this outside of your project to get a better indication of the actual issue.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following:

```
TextBox.AcceptsReturn = True;
```