# Start a new line in wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, carriage-return

I created a small GUI with WPF, containing a Textbox.
I want the user to have the ability to start a new line .
How do I let the user start a new line in the WPF textbox (with \n or \r)? 
I want the user to be able to start a new line by pressing "enter".

Answer (score 96, accepted):

have you try set on your textbox following property:

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" (or auto)
AcceptsReturn="True"
```

Comment: Is TextWrapping a necessity? Is VerticalScrollBarVisibility a necessity? Note that AcceptsReturn is a bool, not a string, but that is easy to figure out.

Comment: No, the TextWrapping is not necessary nor is VerticalScrollBarVisibility. AcceptsReturn is a bool, but in XAML you still set it as if it were a string exactly how this answer shows.

Answer (score 14):

The textbox control has an "AcceptsReturn" property (True/False) that you need to set to True.

You can set it in the Visual Studio IDE Properties box or you can set it within the code.

```
textbox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the `AcceptReturn = true` property, if the user wants to start a new line by pressing the enter key you will need to check these properties:

1. `IsReadOnly` should be False. If you set this to True, then obviously the Enter key won't work.
2. Verify the control containing the TextBox is not clipping the TextBox, else it will appear that the Enter key did not work.