# C# StreamReader and StreamWriter for search A word in afile?

Tags: c#, file, streamreader, streamwriter

Can anybody help me write multiple lines to Text file and then search a specific word in that file. I hope the code will use (File.Exists) if any.... thank you in advance
My Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;



    string lines = textBox1.Text;

        StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.txt",true);

        file2.WriteLine(lines);

        file2.Close();


    string text = textBox1.Text;

    StreamReader file3 = new StreamReader("D:\\test.txt");

    while ((line = file3.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name "+text+" is Found!");
           textBox2.Text = text;

            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    file3.Close();

}
```

Comment: I might be confused about what you're asking, but it seems like you answered your own question in your question.

Comment: Indeed, this code should get the job done pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer.... The problem is that I cant write multiple lines in textbox1 and move them to a file then read the text from that file to fine that searched word and display it in the textBox2

Comment: Then this question is actually about multiple lines in a text box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start a new line in wpf textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865375/start-a-new-line-in-wpf-textbox)

Comment: yes, but writing multiple lines in a file doesn't work and when read the file  it doesn't display the searched word in textBox2? anyway thank you I will check it again ....

Comment: thank you all .... I lastly found my Answer I modified the code as below:                 
                 while ((line = file3.ReadToEnd()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Name "+text+" is Found!");
                   textBox2.Text = text;
                    
                    break;
                }

                counter++;
            }

            file3.Close();

Answer (score 0):

thank you all .... I lastly found my Answer I modified the code as below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        string lines = textBox1.Text;

            StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.txt",true);

            file2.WriteLine(lines);

            file2.Close();

        string text = textBox2.Text;

        StreamReader file3 = new StreamReader("D:\\test.txt");

        while ((line = file3.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Name "+text+" is Found!");
               textBox2.Text = text;

                break;
            }

            counter++;
        }

        file3.Close();



    }
```