# WPF AcceptsReturn not working

Tags: c#, wpf

Am trying to set a `TextBox` for multiline. However it is not working. **When the `Enter` key is pressed it leaves the `TextBox` instead of new line.** Checking online for solution, I have come across [TextBox Enter does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829261/in-wpf-textbox-enter-does-not-add-a-new-line). I have tried the suggestions mentioned there but still it's not working. It was inside a `ScrollViewer` which I removed but still. I've also tried putting it inside a `Canvas` still no luck. I've seen where `clipping` mentioned but I have not been able to find a solution how to remove that. I have also make it as a `UserControl` and reference it but no luck. However if I create a new `Window` it works. The `TextBox` is inside a `TabItem`. Code Structure is similar to:

```
<Window x:Class="CSD_EMRS.Windows.Code"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Code" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <Grid>
                <GroupBox>
                    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UPDATE:** Sorry guys, am working on inherited code and just saw that there's a `PreviewKeyDown` code changing the behaviour.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to add your code